# Working with hibernate multiple Criteria with logical AND

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jakarta-ee

So far i've been working with only a case with 2 properties with and as logical operator so i use LogicalExpression like so

```
Criterion eqRef = Restrictions.eq("referenceID", referenceId);
Criterion eqType = Restrictions.eq("verificationType", type);
LogicalExpression and = Restrictions.and(eqRef, eqType);
```

this time along its more than 2 so i'm a bit confused.say this time i've added username property i can do the normal chaining with

```
session.createCriteria(this.getPersistentClass())
.add(Restrictions.eq("referenceID", referenceId))
.add(Restrictions.eq("verificationType", type))
.add(Restrictions.eq("username", username))
.list();
```

but now i don't know which kind of logical operator used between them.i'm also tempted to do this:

```
Criterion eqRef = Restrictions.eq("referenceID", referenceId);
Criterion eqType = Restrictions.eq("verificationType", type);
Criterion equsername = Restrictions.eq("username", username);
LogicalExpression and = Restrictions.and(eqRef, eqType);
LogicalExpression secondand = Restrictions.and(and, equsername);
```

i've see the eqAll too but i've never used it before.So do you have any idea about that?How do you do it, and thanks for reading this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you're "AND"-ing all of your restrictions the grouping is irrelevant, so you can just continue on as in your second example, as there's nothing to be gained by subgrouping them, e.g.

```
.add(Restrictions.eq("referenceID", referenceId)).add(Restrictions.eq("verificationType", type)).add(Restrictions.eq("username", username))...
```

You do run into this problem where you need to group mixed "AND" and "OR" queries, if you want to group multiple "OR" values you can also add Criteria to a [Disjunction](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Disjunction.html)

Answer (score 1):

Adding these restrictions individually creates a relation of 'AND' between them. This is good enough for what you need.

Answer (score 0):

> but now i don't know which kind of
>   logical operator used between them.

Good answers already, but as an aside you can use the property `hibernate.show_sql`, set it to true, and you'll be able to see exactly what sql your criteria is producing.

Answer (score -1):

just use this

```
criteria = session.createCriteria(Model.class).add(
                             Restrictions.between("ModelDate", dateMin, dateMax));
```

Comment: Can you explain what "ModelDate", "tglMin", and "tglMax" are?  I don't see them in the question and I have no idea why you would use them.

Comment: ModelDate is date column from model/entity, tglMin & tglMax I mean dateMin & dateMax in between restriction.